# Reading of "licet" in the following sentence

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation

The following sentence is from a 5th-century [book](https://digiliblt.uniupo.it/xtf/view?docId=dlt000338/dlt000338.xml;chunk.id=d1918e1994;toc.depth=1;toc.id=d1918e160;brand=default)

> [12] Rursus terra accepto solis lumine clarescit tantummodo, non
> relucet, luna speculi instar lumen quo illustratur emittit, quia illa
> aeris et aquae, quae per se concreta et densa sunt, faex habetur et
> ideo extrema uastitate denseta est, nec ultra superficiem quauis luce
> penetratur; haec licet et ipsa finis sit, sed liquidissimae lucis et
> ignis aetherii, ideo, quamuis densius corpus sit quam cetera
> caelestia, ut multo tamen terreno purius, fit acceptae luci
> penetrabile, adeo ut eam de se rursus emittat, nullum tamen ad nos
> perferentem sensum caloris

How do I read the sentence " haec licet et ipsa finis sit " in the above context?